# Comments on nomination posts are missing the title in activity history

Tags: bug, comments, election, recent-activity

Posting comments to a nomination post causes the entry in your activity history to look funny (because it's missing a title):

> [image: Comment on nomination post]
>   <sub>*Random empty space from missing text that makes other text look misaligned.*</sub>

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I knew there was a duplicate out there somewhere, but I could not for the life of me find it. -.-